# lateinit property fakeAuthRepository has not been initialized unit testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, android-viewmodel

I am using unit testing when I run test I am getting following exception

ateinit property fakeAuthRepository has not been initialized
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property fakeAuthRepository has not been initialized

below my ViewModel test where test giving an exception

```
internal class SignInViewModelTest{
    private val _login =  MutableStateFlow<UiStateObject<SignInResponse>>(UiStateObject.EMPTY)

         @Mock
        lateinit var backendApi:BackendApi

    lateinit var fakeAuthRepository: FakeAuthRepository
    lateinit var authRepository: AuthRepository
    private lateinit var viewModel: SignInViewModel
    @Before
    fun setUp() {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        fakeAuthRepository = FakeAuthRepository(backendApi)
        authRepository = AuthRepository(backendApi)
        viewModel = SignInViewModel(authRepository)

    }

    var login = _login

    @Test
    fun `testing repository`() = runBlockingTest {

        val fake = fakeAuthRepository.login("kyodgorbek@gmail.com", "12345678", "android", "123455")
        val real = authRepository.login("kyodgorbek@gmail.com", "12345678", "android", "123455")
        assertEquals(fake, real)


    }



}
```

Comment: Nevermind, I see how this is a new issue. It's complaining about `fakeAuthRepository` and never `backendApi` anymore?

Comment: @tenfour04 yes you are right

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint inside `setUp` and run your test in debug mode to make sure `setUp` is getting called.

Comment: I have debug it it is not working at all

Comment: Are you using junt4 or 5?

Comment: @Jens junit5 I am using

Comment: You added junit4 annotations not junit 5

Comment: @Jens even I have added junit4 annotation it is giving the same problem

Comment: *@before is junit 4 use @BeforEach*

Comment: @Jens can you explain what you mean in coding sample or answer

Comment: If you are using junit 5 replace *@Before with @BeforeEach*

Comment: @Jens thank you it helped  if you edit your comment as answer I will  accept it thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Before` is junit4 annotation.

If you are using junit5 you have to replace it with `@BeforeEach`.